# Placing MKMapView behind a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I'm trying to get a `MKMapView` to appear behind a `UITableView`. Currently I'm overriding `viewForHeaderInSection` and adding a subview to it.

This works fine, however I'm looking to achieve something more like Path's header image, where the map will stay in place and the table view below will reveal more of the map, rather than scrolling the entire view up and down.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question :| Maybe adding images might help?

Comment: I'm trying to place a MapView behind the Table, rather than embedding it into a cell. Similar to how Path place an image at the top - without overriding the HeaderView as this doesn't give the same effect http://bit.ly/15Kwi2x

Comment: I see, and should anything happen to the MapView if the user scroll the tableView below?

Comment: It should remain in place. Overriding the header view means that the map scrolls with the table - I don't want that.

Comment: Then why do you want to add it to the tableView? Just create a separate mapView and a tableView, with a smaller frame bellow it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place the map view directly behind the table view, you can use:

```
[[self tableView] setBackgroundView:[self mapView]];
```

The table view will obscure the map view *most* of the time but you could create a blank view in the table header (where your map view is currently) to allow the table view to sit a little further down the screen and show the top section of the map view behind it. You could perhaps observe the scrollView methods to determine the scroll offset and zoom in/out of the map etc as necessary.

Comment: Ah, using a BackgroundView is a clever idea. I guess that I could also work out how far the table view has been pulled or pushed to extend the height of the background view, to create a sort of stretching effect?

Comment: From the docs: `A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the size of the table view. This view is placed as a subview of the table view behind all cells, header views, and footer views.` You could certainly determine the offset of how far the table has been scrolled and attenuate your table header view as you see fit by observing `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

Comment: If I set a background view then, will it automatically be the height of the table? I'd only want it to be about `120.0f` in height.

Comment: The documentation for `UITableView` would suggest so. You could always add the map view as a subview of the background and set the height there? If not, your original approach of adding it to the table header may be your best bet depending on the effect you're looking to create.

Comment: Awesome - thanks, I'll give it a go. At least now I have a couple of options.